# Plotting a GeoDataFrame polyline as an arrow

Tags: python, visualization, geopandas

I have a number of .kml files which I've converted into geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrames which consist of polylines. These lines represent ocean currents and so need a direction. Is it possible to plot a GeoDataFrame line as an arrow?

This is the code I'm using to plot it:

```
geopandas.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'
cold1 = geopandas.read_file('Currents/Cold 1 (S).kml', driver='KML')
cold1.plot(edgecolor='dimgrey',ax=ax,linewidth=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the start and end of the line in geopandas matches what you intended?

If you have attribute data for OD, you can transfer geopandas to networkX for drawing an accurate arrow. (However, it is necessary to specify the exact coordinate values for each node)

Another approach is to draw arrows using matplotlib with start and end points on each line. If you want to refer to an example of how to draw an arrow after converting the start and end points of each line to numbers.